# asp.net core Api - insert new row in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an address object in a database through an asp.net core api. I'm using Postman to invoke the method.

Class:

```
namespace LC.Tools.API.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MailerController : Controller
    {
        Data.LCToolsDbContext _context;

        public MailerController(Data.LCToolsDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAddress(int client, string name, string email)
        {
            Address adr = new Address() { ClientId = client, Name = name, Email = email };
            _context.MailerAddresses.Add(adr);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(adr);
        }
    } }
```

URL (using POST):

```
http://localhost:50444/api/mailer/createAddress?client=1&name=test&email=mail@mail.no
```

I also have a break point in the method, but it never hits. I don't get any error message, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: can you show the View?

Comment: Have a look at [URL Encoding](https://www.google.nl/search?q=URL+encoding) your values. An @ sign is not valid in a URL. Use %40, you'll be fine.

Comment: Why not pass in the `address` object?

Comment: `[Route("api/[controller]")]` add this

Comment: And use a model instead of so many parameters. 
`CreateAddress(CreateAddressModel model)` where the model contains the properties for  client, name and email

Comment: I've updated the original post with the whole class. I can look into passing in an address object when I get the basics to work

Comment: Try `/api/Mailer/CreateAddress?…`, I think the route is case sensitive. Also, do you get any response from the call? What’s the response’s status code?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch The [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) explicitly allows the `@` as part of the `pchar` character class. No need to encode it; in fact, you actually do not need to encode most characters.

Comment: I changed the call to match case, but the response is 404 Not Found. So there must be something essential I'm missing

Comment: Any reason you're using `[HttpPost]` but pass the parameters via URL(`[HttpGet]`)?

Comment: try post to http://localhost:50444/api/mailer?client=1&name=test&email=mail@mail.no

Comment: @TheRuler Then please try the case-corrected URL. If that doesn’t work, change the `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpPost("CreateAddress")]`.

Comment: @poke true... I jumped a bit there ;)

Comment: Try `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see @Rick van den Bosch's comment but still you would like to specify the route with action. use this

```
 [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Answer (score 1):

See @Ayvaras' comment. Since you're building a Web API controller, you don't have to specify the action name in your URL. The HttpPost points all POST actions to the mailer controller towards the CreateAddress method.

Your POST URL should be:

```
http://localhost:50444/api/mailer?client=1&name=test&email=mail@mail.no
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Thanks Ayvaras,

> [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

did the trick. Now that the method is found I can look into how to pass an object instead of using querystring

Answer (score 0):

You are not using POST correctly.

If you use POST you should not be sending parameters through the query string, you should use the request body. Even though, if you still have to send them via query string you should use the `FromQuery` attribute in your action parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAddress([FromQuery] int client, [FromQuery] string name, [FromQuery] string email)
{
    Address adr = new Address() { ClientId = client, Name = name, Email = email };
    _context.MailerAddresses.Add(adr);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(adr);
}
```

**Edit**: Use `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` to append the action name in your action route.

Comment: POST is *not* required to use the HTTP body only to communicate data. Just like you use the rest of the URL, you can just use query arguments at any moment, for any HTTP method. That being said, according to the comments, the endpoint is not found, so your suggestion will not help here.

Comment: @poke It's not required but it's not a convention. If a customer or developer has to implement this API it won't look like the usual thing to use POST but send parameters via query string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the controllers routing scheme, it's also possible to specify the endpoint name by doing the following

```
[HttpPost("createAddress")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAddress(int client, string name, string email)
{
    [...]
}
```